# Is there any functional language compiler/runtime which optimizes chained iterations?

Tags: scala, optimization, functional-programming, compiler-optimization

Will any functional language compiler/runtime reduce all chained iterations into one when applyable? From the programmer perspective we could optimize the functional code with such constructs as lazyness and streams but I am interested to know the other side of the story.
My functional example is written in Scala but please don't limit your answers to that language.

Functional way:

```
// I assume the following line of code will go
// through the collection 3 times, one for creating it
// one for filtering it and one for summing it 
val sum = (1L to 1000000L).filter(_ % 2 == 0).sum // => 250000500000
```

I would like the compiler to optimize to the imperative equivalent of:

```
/* One iteration only */
long sum, i;
for (i = 1L, sum = 0L; i <= 1000000L; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    sum += i;
}
```

Comment: We *could* even optimize this to compile-time evaluation: `val sum = 250000500000`. Maybe some compilers do?

Comment: @leemes That is correct, but I am interested in the case where the values are **not known** at compile time.

Comment: can you give pseudocode of what you'd like the compiler to produce?

Comment: @AdamRabung: I would like the compiler to optimize to the equivalent of the imperative version.

Comment: `sum $ filter even [1 .. 1000000]` automatically does only one traversal in any reasonable Haskell implementation (and runs in constant small space). Fusing away the list is unfortunately not something GHC does by itself, you have to jump through quite a few hoops with rewrite rules to achieve that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Would you please elaborate with resources that comprove that? If that's the case then please respond with an answer.

Comment: @tsenart Since you seem interested, I have written up a partially detailed answer. I hope it is accessible even without much Haskell knowledge.

Comment: You're looking for "deforestation" or "fusion" optimizations. These have been extensively researched in the context of Haskell, but are also available in some more restricted forms in other FP-ish compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted two blog posts about exactly this topic a few years ago:

http://jnordenberg.blogspot.de/2010/03/scala-stream-fusion-and-specialization.html
http://jnordenberg.blogspot.de/2010/05/scala-stream-fusion-and-specialization.html

Note that the specialization and optimization done by the Scala compiler has improved quite a bit since then (probably in Hotspot as well), so the results might be even better today.

Answer (score 14):

Haskell is a non-strict language by definition, all implementations I'm aware of use lazy evaluation to provide the non-strict semantics.

The analogous code (with arguments for the start and end, so a compile-time evaluation isn't possible)

```
val :: Int -> Int -> Int
val low high = sum $ filter even [low .. high]
```

computes the sum with only one traversal, and in constant small memory. `[low .. high]` is syntactic sugar for `enumFromTo low high`, and the definition of `enumFromTo` for `Int` is basically

```
enumFromTo x y
    | y < x     = []
    | otherwise = go x
      where
        go k = k : if k == y then [] else go (k+1)
```

(actually, GHC's implementation uses unboxed `Int#`s for reasons of efficiency in the worker `go`, but that has no influence on the semantics; for other `Integral` types, the definition is analogous).

The definition of `filter` is

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter _pred []    = []
filter pred (x:xs)
  | pred x         = x : filter pred xs
  | otherwise      = filter pred xs
```

and `sum`:

```
sum     l       = sum' l 0
  where
    sum' []     a = a
    sum' (x:xs) a = sum' xs (a+x)
```

Assembling that, even without any optimisations, the evaluation would proceed

```
sum' (filter even (enumFromTo 1 6)) 0
-- Now it must be determined whether the first argument of sum' is [] or not
-- For that, the application of filter must be evaluated
-- For that, enumFromTo must be evaluated
~> sum' (filter even (1 : go 2)) 0
-- Now filter knows which equation to use, unfortunately, `even 1` is False
~> sum' (filter even (go 2)) 0
~> sum' (filter even (2 : go 3)) 0
-- 2 is even, so
~> sum' (2 : filter even (go 3)) 0
~> sum' (filter even (go 3)) (0+2)
-- Once again, sum asks whether filter is done or not, so filter demands another value or []
-- from go
~> sum' (filter even (3 : go 4)) 2
~> sum' (filter even (go 4)) 2
~> sum' (filter even (4 : go 5)) 2
~> sum' (4 : filter even (go 5)) 2
~> sum' (filter even (go 5)) (2+4)
~> sum' (filter even (5 : go 6)) 6
~> sum' (filter even (go 6)) 6
~> sum' (filter even (6 : [])) 6
~> sum' (6 : filter even []) 6
~> sum' (filter even []) (6+6)
~> sum' [] 12
~> 12
```

That would of course be less efficient than the loop, since for each element of the enumeration, a list cell has to be produced, then for each element passing the filter a list cell has to be produced, only to be immediately consumed by the sum.

Let's check that the memory usage is indeed small:

```
module Main (main) where

import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let (low, high) = case args of
                        (a:b:_) -> (read a, read b)
                        _       -> error "Want two args"
    print $ sum $ filter even [low :: Int .. high]
```

and run it,

```
$ ./sumEvens +RTS -s -RTS 1 1000000
250000500000
      40,071,856 bytes allocated in the heap
          12,504 bytes copied during GC
          44,416 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          21,120 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0        75 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0003s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.01s  (  0.01s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.01s  (  0.01s elapsed)

  %GC     time       6.1%  (7.6% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    4,367,976,530 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  91.8% of total user, 115.8% of total elapsed
```

It allocated about 40MB for 0.5 million list cells<sup>(1)</sup> and a bit of change, but the maximum residency was about 44KB. Running it with an upper limit of 10 million, the overall allocation (and running time) grows by a factor of 10 (minus constant stuff), but the maximum residency remains the same.

<sup>(1)</sup> GHC fuses the enumeration and the filter, and produces only the even numbers in the range at type `Int`. Unfortunately, it cannot fuse away `sum`, since that is a left fold, and GHC's fusion framework only fuses right folds.

Now, to fuse also the `sum`, one must do a lot of work teaching GHC to do that with rewrite rules. Fortunately, that has been done for many algorithms in the `vector` package, and if we use that,

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import System.Environment (getArgs)

val :: Int -> Int -> Int
val low high = U.sum . U.filter even $ U.enumFromN low (high - low + 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let (low, high) = case args of
                        (a:b:_) -> (read a, read b)
                        _       -> error "Want two args"
    print $ val low high
```

we get a faster programme that doesn't even allocate any list cells anymore, the pipeline *is* really rewritten to the loop:

```
$ ./sumFilter +RTS -s -RTS 1 10000000
25000005000000
          72,640 bytes allocated in the heap
           3,512 bytes copied during GC
          44,416 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
          17,024 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.01s  (  0.01s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.01s  (  0.01s elapsed)

  %GC     time       1.0%  (1.2% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    7,361,805 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  97.7% of total user, 111.5% of total elapsed
```

Here's the core that GHC produces for (the worker of) `val`, if somebody is interested:

```
Rec {
Main.main_$s$wfoldlM'_loop [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int#
[GblId, Arity=3, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType LLL]
Main.main_$s$wfoldlM'_loop =
  \ (sc_s303 :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
    (sc1_s304 :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
    (sc2_s305 :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case GHC.Prim.># sc1_s304 0 of _ {
      GHC.Types.False -> sc_s303;
      GHC.Types.True ->
        case GHC.Prim.remInt# sc2_s305 2 of _ {
          __DEFAULT ->
            Main.main_$s$wfoldlM'_loop
              sc_s303 (GHC.Prim.-# sc1_s304 1) (GHC.Prim.+# sc2_s305 1);
          0 ->
            Main.main_$s$wfoldlM'_loop
              (GHC.Prim.+# sc_s303 sc2_s305)
              (GHC.Prim.-# sc1_s304 1)
              (GHC.Prim.+# sc2_s305 1)
        }
    }
end Rec }
```

Comment: Right, but what about strict languages?

Comment: Huh, I'd think it would be possible for a compiler in a strict language too to rewrite it to the loop. But I don't know if any compiler for a strict functional language has been taught that.

Comment: The question specifically mentions laziness as something that the OP is not interested in for these purposes; and the example is in scala.

Comment: I read that as the OP isn't interested in manually inserted laziness, since in that case, one could equally well just write the loop and be done with it, in particular after the OP asked for elaboration of my comment.

Comment: Thanks so much for this super detailed answer! It was really insightful. I am not flagging the question as answered though, because I want people from other more strict functional languages to have their shot at it.

Comment: Loop fusion has been implemented in OCaml and at least one proprietary strict Haskell compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In theory as one commenter wrote, the compiler could reduce this to the result at compile time. It is not unimaginable that this is done with some macros, but not very likely in general cases.

If you insert a `.view` call, you get lazy semantics in Scala, and hence only one iteration will be performed, albeit not as plain as your imperative code:

```
val lz = (1L to 1000000L).view.filter(_ % 2 == 0) // SeqView (lazy)!
lz.sum
```

---

P.S. Your assumption is wrong that there are otherwise three iterations. `(1L to 1000000L)` creates a `NumericRange` which does not involve any iteration over the elements. So the `.view` saves you one iteration.

Comment: In terms of final result your solution is indeed optimized.
My question, as stated in the above text, refers to **compiler** optimizations of the equivalent of the first snippet in **any** functional language.

Re your P.S: I haven't decompiled the generated Java Byte code so I can't be sure but the list has to be constructed and initialized in **some** way. That at lower level must be done with an iteration I believe. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: To represent `(1L to 1000000L)` you need a type that stores `1L` and `1000000L`. Why would you want to iterate? That may happen when you try to print that object (`toString`), of course.